# AgenDAV and Baikal -- Can't login

Tags: caldav

I have a Baikal DAV-Server running and it is already working fine with roundcube (contacts) and my Android phone. Now I wanted to setup AgenDAV as web-client. So far so good but when I try to login into the AgenDAV front-end I always get a wrong username / password error.

The login data is 100& correct as it is working on Roundcube / Android. I also tested it with curl...

```
curl --basic --user my-user:my-pass http://dav.site.com/cal.php/principals/my-user/
```

... and this works aswell. Still, if I login via AgenDAV the Baikal log throws:

```
[IP] - - [21/Oct/2013:11:56:28 +0200] "OPTIONS /cal.php/principals/my-user/ HTTP/1.1" 401 729 "-" "AgenDAV v1.3.0-dev"
```

Any help is really appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've just made it work with the help of http://www.trbtr.de/pmw/pmwiki.php/Text/Baikal-caldavzap

Use a text editor to open config.js in CalDavZAP's main directory.

```
disable globalAccountSettings
change globalNetworkCheckSettings to the URL for your server:
var globalNetworkCheckSettings={href: 'http://your.server.xyz/bk/cal.php/principals/',... (leave or change other params as you like)
enable var globalUseJqueryAuth=true;
```